# Multi-dimensional MLE Gaussian

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, estimation, gauss-sums

I wonder that what is the mu and sigma formula MLE (maximum likelihood estimates) for a 3 dimension gaussian? It is the same form  as 1 and 2 dimension (+ 1 mu and sigma for the new vector)?

Comment: It's the same, except you also have a covariance matrix.

Comment: thanks for your answer alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As often happens with MLEs, it's just what you would expect.

The MLE for the matrix of covariances has the sample size $n$ in the denominator and the entries are the sample variances and sample covariances.  This matrix has a [Wishart distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

When I first saw the derivation of the MLE of the $3\times3$ or $p\times p$ variance, I was struck by the technique by which it turned out to be useful to view a scalar as the trace of a $1\times 1$ matrix.  See this section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices#Maximum-likelihood_estimation_for_the_multivariate_normal_distribution